Is there any graphing software for linux that has a capability of curve fitting manually selected data?
I have so far used MATLAB (Windows and Linux), PASCO (Windows).
The problem with MATLAB is that it doesn't work on my Linux (parrot) because of my GPU being intel integrated and  MATLAB doesn't seem to be able to use it in Linux platform even though  it works well on Windows.
Elaborating the by selective curve fit, For example take stress-strain curve and I want to use a linear curve fit to only the area where the graph seems to increase linearly. In Pasco there is an option to select ther area where the points can be higlighted to be curve fit.
Any Linux software capable of that ?
I have even tried veusz, GNU octave(too hard to use).
